# Discovering SharePoint Server in a domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, domain

Is it possible to find a SharePoint server machine in a domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this way.

- if I know the Central Admin of sharePoint then I will check it from servers in the farm, which will list all the SharePoint Servers in that farm.
- Another approach, build a PowerShell script which will check and list if any of the servers in the domain has "SharePoint timer Service Installed". something like this http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26428474/Powershell-determine-if-service-exists-on-remote-computer.html

Comment: this is very clever!

Comment: Thank you! Wonderful Idea! Still I face some issue with this.. i can able to track other services like "MpsSvc", "WinRM" but not the SharePoint services like "SPAdminV4" ,"SPTimerV4"

Answer (score 0):

To detect all your servers in a domain, here is what you could do:

Use the following PowerShell code to retrieve the list of all your servers from AD. You can further filter by operating system or OU if necessary.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select -Expand DNSHostName
```

Once you have the list of servers you can run the following PowerShell code to check if SharePoint was installed on that machine (replace the COMPUTER_NAME_HERE with the actual FQDN of the computer you are targeting):

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER_NAME_HERE -ScriptBlock { 

    Function Test-RegistryValue($regkey, $name) {
    $exists = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regkey" -Name "$name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If (($exists -ne $null) -and ($exists.Length -ne 0)) {
        Return $true
        }

        Return $false
    }

    return ((Test-RegistryValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0" "Version") -or
            (Test-RegistryValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0" "Version") -or
            (Test-RegistryValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0" "Version"))

}
```

You can combine the above approach with the services approach already mentioned in another answer if you would like to check if SharePoint Timer service is running on that box.

As an alternative I can suggest you take a look at our free tool called [SPDocKit Pulse](https://pulse.spdockit.com/) that can perform auto-discover of SharePoint servers for you but it also provides additional info about your servers, SQL servers, roles and overall health.